# Place elements in a single div in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am new to jQuery and I am working with an API to do the following.

1. Get Multiple values from the API like name, place, weather forecast etc.
2. I have a bootstrap structure with the following code:-

   ```
   <div id="place_here" class="row">

   </div>
   ```

   I want to place the data that I get from the API in this DIV.
3. Only thing that I want to do is get put all that data into a single div and place that div into above row div to create a beautiful table like structure. Something like this:-

   ```
   var str = '<div class="col-md-4">' + newoverview + '</div>';
   ```

   (newoverview is a string from JSON that I get. However that is only a single value that I want to place in my `div class = "col-md-4"` tag above. I want to insert more values as well.

Problems:-

1. I cannot(or don't know) how to use global variable in JQuery. Whenever I log a variable value in console it give me a `null` . I know that's because JSON is asynchronous but I don't know a work around this.
2. I tried using multiple functions and passing values one by one and adding div by div. However that is not doing what I want to do and gives a messed up structure.

How can I collect all the required values that I get in a JSON and combine them in a single div and place it in a div in my HTML structure.

Edit:- Code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#Search_Button").click(function() {
    var name;
    name = $("#value").val();
    if(!name){
      console.log("Enter a name");
    }
    search(name);
  });

  function search(name){
    var url = "url_here";
    $.getJSON(url,function(data){
      $.each(data.results,function(i,j){
        displayImage(j.path);
        displayOverview(j.id);
      });
    });
  }

  function displayOverview(id){
    var url = "url_here";
    $.getJSON(url,function(data){
      var overviewx = data.overview;
      var newoverview='';
      for(var x=0;x<overviewx.length && x<100 ;x++){
        newoverview+=overviewx[x];
      }
      var str = '<div class="col-md-4">' + newoverview + 
        '</div>';
      $("#place_here").append(str);
    });
  }

  function displayImage(id){
    var url = "url_here";
    var str = '<img src="' + url + '"</img>';
    $("#place_here").append(str);
    console.log(str);
  }
});
```

I want to place both(and maybe more) tags in a single `div` from `displayOverview` and from `displayImage` and place that `div` into my main HTML Structure.

Comment: you're going to have to post some javascript here... you're not giving us much to go on

Comment: Can you provide the js code so that we can see what is going on over there

Comment: Hey Guys.! Just added my code.!

Answer (score 0):

This is just an exemple !

to prevent asynchronous processing,we use callbacks

```
function getItem(){
    var dfd = jQuery.Deferred();
    var url_to_json = 'json/test.json';

        $.getJSON(url_to_json, function(data) {
          dfd.resolve(data);
        });
    return $dfd.promise();
}
```

when you need a the response you just :

```
getItem.done(function(data){
 console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Can I declare `var items = [];` outside of `$.getJSON` and use that as a global array.?

Comment: to do that you need to use a $.Deferred(), i update my answer